# Appending a string variable to a fixed string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, append

I have a variable that is entered at a prompt:

```
my $name = <>;
```

I want to append a fixed string `'_one'`to this (in a separate variable).

E.g. if `$name = Smith` then it becomes `'Smith_one'`

I have tried several various ways which do not give me the right results, such as:

```
my $one = "${name}_one";
```

^ The `_one` appears on the next line when I print it out and when I use it, the _one is not included at all.

Also:

```
my $one = $name."_one";
```

^ The `'_one'` appears at the *beginning* of the string.

And:

```
my $end = '_one';
my $one = $name.$end;
or 
my $one = "$name$end";
```

None of these produce the result I want, so I must be missing something related to how the input is formatted from the prompt, perhaps. Ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to string appending: When you read a line (e.g. via `<>`), then the record input separator is *included* in that string; this is usually a newline `\n`. To remove the newline, `chomp` the variable:

```
    my $name = <STDIN>; # better use explicit filehandle unless you know what you are doing
    # now $name eq "Smith\n"
    chomp $name;
    # now $name eq "Smith"
```

To interpolate a variable into a string, you usually don't need the `${name}` syntax you used. These lines will all append `_one` to your string and create a new string:

```
    "${name}_one"  # what you used
    "$name\_one"   # _ must be escaped, else the variable $name_one would be interpolated
    $name . "_one"
    sprintf "%s_one", $name
    # etc.
```

And this will append `_one` to your string and still store it in `$name`:

```
    $name .= "_one"
```

Comment: ahhh that is interesting about the newline character - chomp immediately solves the problem! I'd tried those methods of appending, too, with no luck - but now they all work! Thanks!

Comment: Funny; I was thinking how much better to use `"${name}_one"` than awkward constructs like `"$name\_one"` or `$name . "_one"`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your edit. By now, I'm also in the “`${foo}` is clear syntax, not an anachronistic bash-ism” camp, and that my original suggestions were worse. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - that's really helpful. In case it helps anyone else trying to fix / set the date modified of files downloaded from Google Photos or via WhatsApp (which strips all the exif data), I used the following:

This will work with WhatsApp type stuff in the format 'IMG-20170721-WA0009.jpg', and set hours, mins and seconds to 01 01 01

```
find . -name \* | perl -lne 'my $a=$_; s/[^\d]+(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})-.*/$1$2$3/ && print "touch -t ${_}0101.01\ \"${a}\"" '
```

this fixes images like '20170721_063856.jpg'

```
find . -name \* | perl -lne 'my $a=$_; s/.*(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*/$1$2$3$4$5.$6/ && print "touch -t $_\ \"$a\"" '
```

- and again just add the `| bash -x` to get it to actually execute. Those search an entire directory, in case you're looking for videos / non-jpgs too